# Does the simplicity of the zeta zeros imply the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

If the Riemann zeros are proved to be simple, that is, have multiplicity ${m_f (\alpha)}=1$ such that their Taylor series about the point $\alpha$ has the form
\begin{equation}
  f (t) = c (t - \alpha)^{m_f (\alpha)} + (...)
\end{equation}
where $c \neq 0$ and $m \geqslant 1$, does it follow that the Riemann hypothesis is true?

Answer (score 1):

It is not known to follow. Conversely, it is not known that the Riemann Hypothesis would imply the simplicity of the zeroes. [And for that matter, I suspect that they are independent, and that the Riemann Hypothesis would be solved before one shows that the zeroes are simple].

The only line of results in either direction stem from a line of inquiry from Montgomery, who showed that a large percentage of the zeroes are simple if the Riemann Hypothesis is true.

Comment: It's pretty easy to show they are simple, see https://fs23.formsite.com/viXra/files/f-1-2-9265569_LTyulPJf_ZSimpleZeros.pdf  and according to Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis, Speiser (1934) proved that the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that ζ ′ ( s ), the derivative of ζ(s), has no zeros in the strip

    0 < ℜ ( s ) < 0.5 .

That ζ has only simple zeros on the critical line is equivalent to its derivative having no zeros on the critical line.

Comment: I cannot find a copy of Speiser, Andreas (1934), "Geometrisches zur Riemannschen Zetafunktion", Mathematische Annalen, 110: 514–521, doi:10.1007/BF01448042, JFM 60.0272.04 on the web, nor on sci-hub, but I would like to check that out

Comment: small typo in definition 3. the 3rd equation shouldnt be there. that is lamba_N_f(t) not lambda_f(t). doesn't change the results though

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889821

Comment: @crow crow , the link to vixra file containing an easy proof of zeros being simple isn't working. Could you provide more information on where to find the article, please? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's not exactly easy, and it's not that straight forward.. I was hoping someone would be able to do some proof via induction based on the scheme i laid out there. http://vixra.org/abs/1702.0273